# EXCEL - Need help combining SUM formula and CONCATENATE in one cell

Tags: excel, vba

Step 1: FIELD B1 equals a date + 14
Step 2: FIELD B1 needs to be formatted to add back preceding zeros

I have successfully created each step but cannot combine them in one field.

```
B1=A1+14
```

and

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(MONTH(B1),"00")&"/",TEXT(DAY(B1)&"/","00"),YEAR(B1))
```

I need to figure out how to combine these two formulas, the second formula uses the RESULT from the first.

EXCEL 2010

Comment: `month(datevalue+14)` and `day(datevalue+14)`?

Answer (score 2):

A simply solution would be to change the use of the TEXT() function.

```
 =TEXT(A1+14,"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

TEXT() has two arguments value and format. In this case I am adding 14 to the date and forcing the format to display a two digit month, two digit day and four digit year. This eliminates the need for the CONCATENATE() function.

Comment: Thank you so much this is much much easier!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get the same results as populating B1 with (=A1+14) and then your CONCATENATE expression by placing the formula below into B1.

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(MONTH(A1+14),"00")&"/",TEXT(DAY(A1+14)&"/","00"),YEAR(A1+14))
```

However, when I place a date of 8/22/2014 in cell A1 the resulting text that I see is "09/5/2014" which may not be your desired result if you're looking for both days and months to be zero-padded.  An alternative that gave me "09/05/2014" as a result was

```
=TEXT(MONTH(A1+14),"00") & "/" & TEXT(DAY(A1+14),"00") & "/" & YEAR(A1+14)
```

Does that get you where you're trying to go?